# Where can I find the Docs of libnautilus?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, gnome

I have been searching on google all day, but I couldn't find any useful information about how to use this lib.
Who can help me?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with [Nautilus Development Extensions](https://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Development/Extensions). It is not comprehensive, but you can get the idea.

Later, you should check the document written by Dave Campd [Nautilus Extensions](http://replay.web.archive.org/20090418175132/http://www.campd.org/stuff/docs/extending-nautilus/NautilusExtensions.html), which contains examples.  Notice I pointed out archive.org because the [original url](http://www.campd.org/stuff/docs/extending-nautilus/NautilusExtensions.html) did not work for me.

Dave's document helps to get the context, which is useful when reading the [API](http://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/).